# Python/Django not refreshing current date on server

Tags: python, django, server

I am using calendar on my server. The current day should be marked but it is not refreshing it. As a result, marked day is the day of server restart. Do you have any solution  to this issue? I want it to mark correct day, not the day on which server occurred. Thanks for help.

UPDATE
This is the code i use

This is entire view function

```
    today = datetime.datetime.today()

    #pulling models from database
    employee = Employee.objects.filter(barberName=Barber)
    reservations = Appointments.objects.all()

    apptDict = {}
    timeList = []

    #make list of all possible appointments for the day
    for x in employee:
        startTime = "28/02/22 " + str(x.barberStartTime)
        endTime = "28/02/22 " + str(x.barberEndTime)
    
    startTimeObj = datetime.datetime.strptime(startTime, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
    endTimeObj = datetime.datetime.strptime(endTime, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')

    while startTimeObj < endTimeObj:
        justTimeList = str(startTimeObj).split(" ")[1].split(":")
        timeList.append(justTimeList[0] +  ":" + justTimeList[1])
        startTimeObj += datetime.timedelta(hours=0.5)
    apptDict["possibleTimes"] = timeList

    #make dictionary of already made appointments in form "date": ["time1", "time2", "timeN"]
    for reservation in reservations:
        time = str(reservation.time).split(":")
        timeStr = time[0] + ":" + time[1]
        if str(reservation.date) not in apptDict:
            apptDict[str(reservation.date)] = []
        apptDict[str(reservation.date)].append(str(timeStr))
        if reservation.date < today.date():
            apptDict[str(reservation.date)] = ["Over"]
    
    #write to json file
    with open("reservations/static/reservations/scripts/appointments.json", "w") as outfile:
        json_object = json.dumps(apptDict, indent=4)
        outfile.write(json_object)

    context = {
        "place": Place,
        "barber": Barber,
        "service": Service,
        "calendar": newCalendar(datetime.datetime.today().month, datetime.datetime.today().year, Barber),
        "employee": employee,
        "availableTimes": timeList,
        "apptDict": apptDict,
        "availTimes": timeList
    }

    if request.method == "POST":
        postCopy = request.POST.copy()
        postCopy['time'] = datetime.datetime.strptime('15/05/22 ' + postCopy['time'], '%d/%m/%y %H:%M').time()
        postCopy['phone'] = str(postCopy['phone'])
        request.POST = postCopy
        form = AppointmentForm(request.POST or NONE)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'reservations/reserved.html', context)
    return render(request, 'reservations/reservationTime.html', context)
```

This is the part of calendar function. It is supposed to visually mark previous days

```
for x in range(1, int(today.day)):
   cal = cal.replace(">" + str(x) + "<", 'style="color: #808080;">' + str(x) + "<") #marking previous days in month
```

Comment: How are you getting the current date in your calendar?

Comment: datetime.today() it is used inside function

Comment: Do you mind posting the code involved?

Comment: You didn't provide enough code to troubleshoot the issue. However, based on your description, it is 100% that your function to create the calendar is running at import time, where you instead need it to be run from within a view function.

Comment: this is entire view function

Comment: `with open("reservations/static/reservations/scripts/appointments.json", "w") as outfile:` I see you're writing the appointments to a static file. How is appointments.json used by your application? Could this be a caching issue, where Django is serving that file with long-lived caching expiration, and the browser doesn't know to re-request the file?

Comment: It is just a file with generated appointments from sql database, there is no trouble with that one, it works like it is supposed to.